# JavaFX: How to set you scrollbars of a ScrollPane in the center?

Tags: java, scrollbar, javafx-8, scrollpane

I have a class that extends Scrollpane.
I have put a pane of 4000 x 4000 (h x w) in the scrollpane.
And I want that my scrollbars are centered in the center, so on 2000 x 2000. So that if I run my GUI, I see whatever I have placed on 2000 x 2000
Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
scrollPane.setVvalue(0.5);
scrollPane.setHvalue(0.5);
```

This set the scrollbars both in the middle of 4000.
The value must be **between 0 and 1**.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the scrollpositions with:

```
scrollPane.setVvalue(2000);
scrollPane.setHvalue(2000);
```

Look here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setVvalue-double-

you can calculate the actual position, you want to scroll to, with the help of the ViewPort Bounds:

```
Bounds bounds = scrollPane.getViewportBounds();
scrollPane.setHvalue(2000 - bounds.getWidth()/2);
scrollPane.setVvalue(2000 - bounds.getHeight()/2);
```

Comment: I found a solution:
scrollPane.setVvalue(0.5);
scrollPane.setHvalue(0.5);
This set the scrollbars both in the middle of 4000.
The value must be between 0 and 1.